# how to get a shareable link ending with '.png' of saved image?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, images

In my app, i am saving an image into the the `ContentVersion` and getting a shareable link using the `ContentDistribution`. I am savinng that shareable link separately in a custom object, so that the user can preview it. This is the code  I used:

```
    ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();
    contentVersion.ContentLocation = 'S';
    contentVersion.PathOnClient = fileName;
    contentVersion.Title = fileName;
    contentVersion.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
    insert contentVersion;

    ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
    cd.name = fileName;
    cd.ContentVersionId = contentVersion.Id;
    cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = true;
    cd.PreferencesAllowPDFDownload = false;
    cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser = true;
    insert cd;
    cd = [SELECT DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ID =:cd.Id];  
    String link = cd.DistributionPublicUrl;
```

The link i got from the above code works fine I if want to preview the image in the browser. But, the problem is that, I have a visualforce page and I want to give the link as an `src` path to the `<img>` tag inside the visualforce page. The `src` path only works when the link ends with '.png'. The link I get from `ContentDistribution` doesnt end with '.png'. So, is there any way to get the shareable link of an image  that ends with '.png' in apex? Also, the visualforce page opens outside of the org.

Comment: Not certain here, so just commenting. You may need to add the mime type and/or use a formula field for this. See if one of those approaches solves the issue.

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand. could you point me to any tutorial or something like that?

Comment: I got the answer. I used [this](https://www.mhamzas.com/blog/2020/01/09/use-salesforce-files-image-file-on-lwc-aura-or-vf-page-as-tag/#) blog.